# Group data based on column value - pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, grouping, bin

I have a dataframe with many columns and different experimental data. I would like to create sub-dataframes/groups based on the value of one of the column.

The column values look as below (just an example):
[column values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2wtQ.png)

What is the smartest way to do this?
As you can see from the figure, since these are experimental data, the column values have some variation but in this case I would like 5 main groups with values that are very close to each other and I would also like to delete all the "transition" points between one value to the next.

I have tried the following:

```
        bin_range = [] # create general bin range:
        for i in np.linspace(1,500,150):
            bin_= i
            for j in df["Vdot_out (hot), m3/h"].values:
                if int(i) == int(j):
                   # print("bin", i)
                    #print("vdot value", j)
                    bin_ = i+1
            bin_range.append(bin_)
            
        df['bins'] = pd.cut(x=df["Column X"], bins=bin_range)
        
        frequency =df['bins'].unique()
        df['RN'] = df.groupby('bins').cumcount().add(1)
        df['number of elements'] = df['bins'].map(df['bins'].value_counts())


        df.drop(df[df['number of elements'] <20].index, inplace = True) # delete transition points
        
        # Connsider the last 200 "stable" points
        groups = df.groupby(df['bins'])
```

Now....this works sometimes, i.e. when I am lucky that the bin ranges include the 5 data groups with no overlap.
However, sometimes it can happen that a bin range is maybe (0-8) and I have column values equal to 3 and 5. Then two groups would be incorporated in one.
If I refine the range too much (like increasing the number of bin ranges), I risk that values very close to each other (like 2.4 and 2.6) end up in different bins (bins 0-2.5 / 2.5-5 / 5-7.5)
There should be some smarter and cleaner way to do this!
Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Can you provide sample as plain text please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you are looking for some kind of clustering algorithm. If you know that you are looking for exactly `k` clusters in `n` observations, you might try k-means like [seen in this gist here.](https://gist.github.com/lobrien/0f95b690644a862fb4dadb73afb7753b)

```py
# code copied from https://gist.github.com/lobrien/0f95b690644a862fb4dadb73afb7753b
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

data = np.array([101, 107, 106, 199, 204, 205, 207, 306, 310, 312, 312, 314, 317, 318, 380, 377, 379, 382, 466, 469, 471, 472, 557, 559, 562, 566, 569])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5).fit(data.reshape(-1,1))
kmeans.predict(data.reshape(-1,1))

# array([4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3,
#       3, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int32)

kmeans.cluster_centers_

#array([[ 337.        ],
#       [ 469.5       ],
#       [ 203.75      ],
#       [ 562.6       ],
#       [ 104.66666667]])
```

Edit:
about the "transitioning points": From the example graph you showed, I would suggest you use mean and standard-deviation to determine the ranges to be kept (e.g. µ+/-3 sigma in case each bins data follows a normal distribution)

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question; however, it is more about `technical` solution rather than about `pandas` code. To do this:

[1] You must sort the observations by ascending order

[2] Create `lag` and `lead` of `n` periods variables. The `n` is up to your choice:

```
for t in [1,2,3,4]:
    df[f'val_lag{t}`] = df['val'].shift(t)
    df[f'val_lead{t}'] = df['val'].shift(-t)
```

[3] You calculate the difference for each observation `n` to its preceding `n-1`, `n-2`, ... and its succeeding `n+1`, `n+2`, ...

```
for t in [1,2,3,4]:
    df[f'diff_lag{t}'] = np.abs(df['val'] - df[f'val_lag{t}'])
    df[f'diff_lead{t}'] = np.abs(df['val'] - df[f'val_lead{t}'])
```

Then the idea is to check condition on those `diff`. If they are larger than any threshold then assign them to `no_group`, if they are less than 'threshold` assign them to group

Comment: You could also use [pd.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) for this like `df['val'].rolling(4).std()` to get the deviation within the last 4 datapoints.